# How read() method of BufferedReader works?

Tags: java

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String [] args){

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter number?");
        int num = br.read();
        System.out.println("You  entered " + num);
    }
}
```

If i give 97 as input then it gives 57 as output.Why? I mean that read method returns int then why it returns another thing? And suppose that if we replace br.read() with (char)reader.read() and if we give input as 97 then output remains same or not i mean that will 97 be converted into character that is 'a'.Kindly make my concept clear .I am confused about when int is represented in ascii or in unicode and further.

Answer (score 2):

`BufferedReader`'s **`read()` method reads a single character only**, so it is actually printing the Unicode value of number 9 (taken first digit from 97) as shown below:

```
char c = '9';
int num = c; //reader.read();
```

**Output**: 57

To solve the issue, you can use `readLine()` to read the input as a line and convert it to `int` as below:

```
int num =  Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `read` method, which just reads a single character and then returns the ascii or unicode value of it. hence when you enter 97 it just reads it as character `9` and then print its ascii value which is `57`.

Please refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read() oracle doc , to get more info of read method.

Apart from `readLine` method of `BufferedReader` , you can use `scanner` class object which comes with option to read int,long,string etc. below sample shows how to read integer.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println("a"+a);
```

Answer (score 0):

read() return one character. String "9" int value is 57.

If input 97 and output 97.

```
int num = Integer.valueOf(reader.readLine()); // num is 97
```

If input 97 and output A.

```
int num = Integer.valueOf(reader.readLine()); // num is 97
char ch = Character.valueOf((char)num); // ch is A
```